# Search for class names

Tags: bug, search

When I search for the term 'ActivityNotFoundException' on SharePoint StackExchange I get no results: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=ActivityNotFoundException.

If I search for 'Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException' I will get 3 results: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException.

This issue has already been discussed on [Search within code block](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/search-within-code-block).

So, to summarize, some users will post "Exception has occurred" while other users will post "System.Exception has occurred". So in order to properly search through SE you always need to search for both variants.

Comment: Search is dot-sensitive.

Comment: IMHO regular SE user is not aware of that.

Comment: I know, that's what we have meta sites for. (and I did not downvote this either)

Comment: Same root cause: whole words search. The current search mechanism SE is using is not searching partial words as far as I can tell. (e.g. searching for rope won't give results with the word "properly")

Comment: I understand. To wrap up the discussion, if you google 'site:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ ActivityNotFoundException' you will get 3 results. I know that Google has 5000 people working only on ranking mechanism, so no search engine can come even close their results.

Comment: Couldn't say it any better. Cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard there was a post about search improvements and even a scheduled maintenance slot was announced but I can't find it anymore, was a month or two back....

Comment: I found at least the MSO starter for it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277584/feedback-requested-search-engine-usage (thanks to @Behaviour)

Comment: @rene the scheduled maintenance was a false alarm, as for the search improvements I haven't noticed anything that mentions the whole word search, which seems as core part of Elastic Search, unless I'm utterly wrong.

Comment: OK, @ShadowWizard it looks like only in my mind things got fixed ;)